# OnEnterBreakMode does not fire

Tags: visual-studio-2012, visual-studio-addins, envdte

Running VS 2012.  I created an add-in.  I want to handle the OnEnterBreakMode event.  The Exec method is called.  I tried returning handled = true/false.  The handler is never invoked.  I tried a few variations of DTE and DTE2.  I go to the Tools menu > click "MyAddIn1" and the Exec method is called.  I verified the event is bound.  I do not know how the life cycle of an add-in works.

`StartEvents` is not an override and it's not connected to anything.  I find that strange...

```
public void Exec(string commandName, vsCommandExecOption executeOption, ref object varIn, ref object varOut, ref bool handled)
        {
            handled = false;
            if(executeOption == vsCommandExecOption.vsCommandExecOptionDoDefault)
            {
                if(commandName == "MyAddin1.Connect.MyAddin1")
                {
                    //handled = true;

                    // Place the following code in the Exec method of the add-in:                           
                    EnvDTE.DebuggerEvents debugEvents = _applicationObject.Events.DebuggerEvents;
                    debugEvents.OnEnterBreakMode += new _dispDebuggerEvents_OnEnterBreakModeEventHandler(Connect.BreakHandler);

                    return;
                }
            }
        }
        private DTE _applicationObject;
        private AddIn _addInInstance;

        // Place the following Event handler code in the add-in:
        // Needed to activate event handlers in Connect.Exec.
        public static void StartEvents(DTE dte)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Events are attached.");
        }

        // OnEnterBreakMode Event.
        public static void BreakHandler(dbgEventReason reason, ref dbgExecutionAction execAction)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Debugger enters break mode. " + "Reason: " + reason.ToString());
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

If you create a local variable for an event, and subscribe to it, then the variable will be freed by GC after scope is left, and your event handler won't fire.

If you make `debugEvents` a member variable then it should work fine.